# What would be different about mathematics if there was no way of avoiding Russell’s Paradox

Tags: soft-question, set-theory

I asked this question to one of my math professors several years ago.  They gave the following answer:

> This is interesting: I have not thought about Russell’s paradox for a while.  My guess is that (as usually happens in mathematics) when someone discovers a paradox it is either shown false or incorporated in some natural way into the canon of mathematics.  Take for a simple example irrational numbers: before their existence was known it was assumed all numbers were rational, but afterwards mathematics was expanded to include them (and the real line was born).
>
> In general we would have to accept a “weaker” form of set theory that allows this paradox to be true, which would make it harder, or impossible, to prove some basic results in mathematics.  In particular, the theory that resolves this paradox relies on the axiom of choice, which is equivalent to many foundational lemmas.  Our understanding of how things worked would change because of this.

I would like to know what kinds of results would be “harder or impossible” to prove if there were no **known** models of set theory in which Russell’s paradox is prevented from occuring.

Comment: What is the meaning of "Russell's paradox is true"?

Comment: Russell's paradox can't be true in a consistent theory; it is really a contradiction, not so much a paradox, for a statement to be equivalent to its negation. The issue about a weaker set theory is a qualitative one, you would need to say which axioms, specifically, are lost in order to make it precise. Also Russell's paradox is already removed in just Zermelo set theory, choice is not essential.

Comment: I apologize: the two paragraphs in block quotes are what my professor told me, but it seems they were wrong on several points.

Comment: What would be different about mathematics if you could prove that $0=1$?

Comment: Russell's paradoxical construction could be true (consistent) if you don't assume $\in$ is total, just treat it as a partial relation.

Comment: @DanielV: Huh? How is $\in$ a total relation? $\{\varnothing\}$ and $\{\{\{\varnothing\}\}\}$ are not in relation to one another, or $\{E\}$ and $\{O\}$, where $E$ and $O$ are the even and odd integers respectively...

Comment: @AsafKaragila In the sense that $A \in B$ is always true or false.

Comment: @DanielV: That is a different thing, and the "totality" here is of the logic, not of the relation.